# Animated toggle in jQuery not linking through

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make an animated list that when an item is clicked, a child UL toggles display and becomes visible. The problem is however, when the user then clicks a child LI within the newly visible List, the display is then toggled again as opposed to the link going to a new page...

My jQuery is...

```
//Product range expander
$('.product-range ul li a').click(function() {
  $(this).parents("li").find("ul").toggle('slow')
  return false;
});
```

Markup...

```
<ul>
<li>
   <a href="#">United Kingdom</a>
       <ul style="display: none;">
           <li><a href="page1.html">Product</a></li>
           <li><a href="page2.html">Product</a></li>
           <li><a href="page3.html">Page</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter your selector so it only targets the first anchor using the CSS2 [child selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html) which only selects direct descendants.

```
$('.product-range > ul > li > a').click(function(e) {
  $(this).parents("li").find("ul").toggle('slow')
  return false;
});
```

Your current selector applies your function to all `a` tags which are nested inside a `li` which is nested inside a `ul` tag regardless of depth.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/P9k9w/9/

Comment: you won't need the second click handler ... the event won't bubble up to the first level anchor because it's not an ancestor of the second level anchors

Answer (score 0):

Try this selector instead

```
$('.product-range > ul > li > a').click(function() {
```

so you will bind the click handler to only those anchor elements which are direct children of the outer `ul li`

Comment: No ... the first level anchor is not a parent of the second level anchors

Answer (score 0):

With attribute selector:

```
$('.product-range ul li a[href="#"]').click(function() {
  $(this).parents("li").find("ul").toggle('slow')
  return false;
});
```

Or you would add different classes to anchor which are links and anchor which only toggle the sublist:

```
$('.product-range ul li a.handle').click(function() {
  $(this).parents("li").find("ul").toggle('slow')
  return false;
});

<ul>
<li>
   <a href="#" class="handle">United Kingdom</a>
       <ul style="display: none;">
           <li><a href="page1.html" class="truelink">Product</a></li>
           <li><a href="page2.html" class="truelink">Product</a></li>
           <li><a href="page3.html" class="truelink">Page</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code:

```
$('.product-range ul li a').click(function() {
var parent_ul = $(this).parents("li").find("ul")

  if(parent_ul.is(':visible')) { // if vizible, go to link
    return true
  } else { // if hidden, show
    parent_ul.toggle('slow')
    return false;
  }
}
```

Or add a class to your ul, so that you can check which one you select